# xarray resampling with certain nan treatment

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

**Problem:**
I'd like to resample a xarray dataset e.g. the sum or mean with each resulting value being nan when at least one of the input values was nan. With pandas I can easily apply an own mean,sum etc. function giving me my preferred nan treatment. xarray also allows resample.apply(own_func) but I have problems defining the own func.

**Example** ([from xarray's documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.resample.html?highlight=resample))**:**

```
dat=np.linspace(0, 11, 12)
dat[2]=np.nan
da = xr.DataArray(dat,
                  coords=[pd.date_range('15/12/1999',
                                        periods=12, 

freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1))],
                      dims='time')

da.resample(time="QS-DEC").sum()
```

**What I get:**

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4)>
array([ 1., 12., 21., 30.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1999-12-01 2000-03-01 2000-06-01 2000-09-01
```

**@JulianGiles answer:**

```
da.resample(time="QS-DEC",skipna=False).mean()
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4)>
array([ 0.5,  4. ,  7. , 10. ])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1999-12-01 2000-03-01 2000-06-01 2000-09-01
```

**What I want:**

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4)>
array([ 1., NAN, 21., 30.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1999-12-01 2000-03-01 2000-06-01 2000-09-01
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it says in the documentation (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html) you can specify `skipna` depending on how do you want nans to be handled.

In your case, specifying `skipna = False` will do it. Since `resample` has been recently modified to defer calculations, you can do it in two ways:

```
da.resample(time="QS-DEC").sum(skipna=False)
```

or the old way (where you put everything inside the `.resample()`):

```
da.resample("QS-DEC", 'time', how='sum', skipna=False)
```

Comment: No, `skipna`says: _Whether to skip missing values when aggregating in downsampling._ My example is about upsampling from monthly to seasonal data.

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding the word 'downsampling'. If you go from monthly to seasonal data you are going from a higher resolution to a lower resolution, that is, you are downsampling. Upsampling would be to increase resolution, for example, going from seasonal to monthly resolution.

Comment: Thanks, I mixed up those two! Still the `skipna` argument does not solve my problem - I extended the questions to show this.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. You have to put the `skipna` argument inside the .sum() operation for it to work. I'll modify my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of xarray `resample` and `reduce`:

```
#Dummy function to see the array grouping
def func(x, axis): #reduce expect a function with axis argument
    print(x)  #To see the array grouping
    return x #Not relevant

da.resample(time="QS-DEC").reduce(func)
```

Nan is in the first quarter (not in the second as you expect)

```
[ 0.  1. nan]
[3. 4. 5.]
[6. 7. 8.]
[ 9. 10. 11.]
```

So, using `np.sum()` the output with the nan is in the first quarter:

```
import numpy as np
da.resample(time="QS-DEC").reduce(np.sum)
```

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4)>
array([nan, 12., 21., 30.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1999-12-01 2000-03-01 2000-06-01 2000-09-01
```

If you want to avoid nan, simply use `np.nansum()`:

```
da.resample(time="QS-DEC").reduce(np.nansum)
```

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 4)>
array([ 1., 12., 21., 30.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1999-12-01 2000-03-01 2000-06-01 2000-09-01
```

The same applies to `np.mean(), np.nanmean(), np.std(), np,nanstd()`, etc.

For more complex functions that are used with reduce, you can see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60627663/6841963